# Passing string value to scene name in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been trying to break down my classes into smaller portions starting with the GameOver and StageClear scenes. My GameOver scene now works fine but I'm stuck with StageClear scene. After research, I found [this topic](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7139). Based on that topic, I ended up with this code to reuse the StageClear scene for my game stages:

```
i++;
NSString *go = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stage%i", i];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[NSClassFromString(go) scene]]];
```

With this code, I want to call the next stage. (Stage1 --> clear game --> i++ --> stage%i = stage2 --> go to Stage2. I get a bad access error code 1 particularly on the transition (third line) along with this message on my stack,

> Assertion failure in -[CCTransitionFade initWithDuration:scene:]

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Guys. Really. Cocos2d is the open-source project. You can freely find the line, that cause assertion failure, in it's code. There are only two assertions in this method. One is that inScene is nil, and the second if the inScene and out scene are the same object. Just check these two cases before posting question here...

Comment: I'm sure the in and out scene are not the same object and i'm also sure that the in scene is not nil so I'm not entirely sure what is going on here. Sorry for asking and thank you for your time.

Comment: add line like CCScene newScene = [NSClassFromString(go) scene]; and check in debugger that it is not nil. or at least check with debugger, what assertion cause crash

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to replace scene using string variable

```
-(void)onEnter{

    [super onEnter];

    Class OtherLayerClassName = NSClassFromString(@"OtherLayer");
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[OtherLayerClassName scene]]];
}
```

don't forget to include neccessary file in this case OtherLayer.h